# Question deleted about life originating from other planets

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

A question was just deleted about Life or humans originating from outside earth. I was just adding this answer when it was deleted:

The Upanishads say that humans were created by Brahma (also called Prajapati) - Prasna Upanishad I. 3-4. There are other Upanishad references to this.

Brahma was created by Iswara. If you are a Vashnavite, then Iswara is Vishnu and Vishnu created Brahma. If you are an advaitist, then Iswara is Saguna Brahman.

Swami Vivekananda makes a passing remark in one of his lectures (Complete Works, V2 p90) of the following:

> By the by, it may interest some of you to know that there are theories on the Vedic philosophy about the origin of life on this earth very similar to those which have been advanced by some modern European scientists. You, of course, all know that there is a theory that life came from other planets. It is a settled doctrine with some Vedic philosophers that life comes in this way from the moon.

You make reference to 'ancient Summerian accounts' do you have a reference for that statement? I am unaware of any generally accepted scientific evidence to this statement.

My question is why was the question deleted? I am able to give an answer.

Comment: It was deleted because it was a repost of a question that had previously been closed: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6714/36

Comment: because it was a repost of a previously closed question does not answer my question. Question is valid, you still do not answer my question as to why it was closed. I have given ample references in my answer, it is a valid question.

Comment: The original question was closed because it's partially a duplicate of an existing question on extraterrestrial life, and the part that's not a duplicate is too speculative for the site.  If the post is edited so that it's a single concrete question, rather than an invitation to speculate, then it may be acceptable.